# Banner ads in collectionview admob ios

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, admob

I have successfully been able to add an admob banner ad to a collection view cell
I have 2 question
First one is :
-Are we allowed to use multiple banner ads in a collectionview 
Second one is:
- are we allowed to use banner ads in collectionview cell
Becuase when the user scroll the ad stay at the index,and another ad is shown at different index

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple banner ads in a CollectionView! Here is a demo by Google how to implement it in a TableView (very similar):

[BannerTableViewExample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/advanced/BannerTableViewExample)

I hope it helps! Please let me know if it works for you. I'm currently working on that as well.